# I have accidentally deleted my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python

I was doing my Logistic Regression with a Neural Network mindset when my submit button disappeared. I followed some instructions that told me to delete the notebook and that a fresh notebook would come back later, but the notebook completely disappeared. Every time I try to access it, I get a 404. I would much appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted jupyter so try to install it from Anaconda Prompt with below command.

`pip install ipykernel` or `conda install ipykernel`

Once its completed then run below command..

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=NewEnv
```

Now run jupyter notebook from anaconda prompt it will work fine..

For More information Visit [Link](https://medium.com/@utkarsh.ankit09/a-simple-guide-for-creating-virtual-environment-in-jupyter-notebook-python-for-windows-1649041aaae1)

Comment: I think what the OP meant was a .ipynb file/notebook was deleted, not the package.